# Sending data to serial port using javascript and jssc.jar

Tags: javascript, serial-port

I need to write a web-based application that will sent data to a display unit (a serial port connecting device) connected by a usb-to-serial converter.

I read that this is possible using a java applet. 
This site shows me that my device works when I run their demo from their online site at:
http://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/wiki/jSSC_Terminal

In the demo site, there is an applet form which:

1. scan available port(s)
2. open the selected port
3. set the configuration settings to the device
4. sent data to be displayed.
5. close the selected port

They are using jssc-terminal.jar (applet) and jssc.jar (library file)

These are the features that I will like to implement in my web app.
But I do not wish to run their applet form, I will like to be able to programmatically do the following when a custom Display button is clicked on my site.

1. open the port
2. set the configuration settings to the device eg: baud rate, byte, partity, stop bit...
3. sent the data to be displayed
4. close the port

Anyone has experience with the jssc.jar library?
Is it possible to simply use the jssc.jar file and communicate it with javascript to do the above?
How can what I want to do be achievable>

Note: the web app is located in the web server on a hosting site.
The display unit is to be connected to a different machine from the server (ie client machine - Window OS)

Answer (score 0):

Windows or Linux? On Linux in order to read or write sth to serial ports (directly) via /dev/* you have to root privileges or some higher. On windows I do not know.

About serial and java
 - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.htm
 - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/javacomm/reference/api/javax/comm/package-summary.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have edited my question to show that the display unit is not connected to the web server. And the client machine is the one that the display unit will be connected to. Client machine will have Window OS.